# React callback to parent not changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. I have a WorkoutCard component:

WorkoutCard:

```
const key = require('weak-key');

function WorkoutCard({ workout }) {

  const { userID } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const closeModalCallback = () => setModalOpen(false);

  return (
    <div className="WorkoutCard" onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>
      <div className="header">
        <h2>{workout.name}</h2>
        <h3>Days</h3>
        {workout.days.map((day) => {
          return (
            <p key={key({})}>{day}</p>
          )
        })}
        <button className="deleteButton" onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
      </div>

      <div className="line"></div>

      <div className="exercises">
        <h3>Exercises</h3>
        {workout.exercises.map((exercise) => {
          return (
            <p key={key({})}>{exercise}</p>
          )
        })}
      </div>

      <EditWorkoutModal key={key({})} modalOpen={modalOpen} closeModalCallback={closeModalCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WorkoutCard;
```

And I have the EditWorkoutModal component:

```
Modal.setAppElement('#root');

function EditWorkoutModal({ modalOpen, workout, closeModalCallback }) {

  const { userID } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={modalOpen} className="editModal">
      <div className="rightHalf">
        <p className='closeButton' onClick={() => closeModalCallback()}>+</p>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default EditWorkoutModal
```

The problem here is that closeModalCallback is not changing the state whatsoever. It is called, but modalOpen is still set to true.

And, this is even more confusing, because I have this functionality working in another part of the app. I have a workouts page that has both WorkoutCard components, as well as a Modal, and it works this way. However, the closeModalCallback on the WorkoutCard components' modals will not work.

Comment: Clicking on the "closeButton" paragraph also means clicking on on the "Workoutcard" div that it is part of. Basic event bubbling. Put the `<EditWorkoutModal …>` outside of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onClick` events bubble up the DOM. For example, see the below snippet (see browser console for output):

```js
const App = () => {
  const parent = () => console.log("parent");
  const child = () => console.log("child");
  return <div onClick={parent}>
    <div onClick={child}>Click me</div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The above logs the following in the console:

```js
> child
> parent
```

In your case, when you click on your child element, the click event bubbles up the DOM, eventually reaching your parent `div` in the parent `WorkoutCard` component, which fires the `onClick` that sets your modal-open state back to `true`. You can stop the event from bubbling by calling `e.stopPropagation()` on your close-modal button's [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event):

```js
onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  closeModalCallback();
}}
```

This way the event won't bubble up to your parent div and trigger the `onClick` which is changing your state.